# extending base instance with prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

This is the situation; I've got a base class (a function) called `Car` and some specific subclasses like `truck`, `bus` or `partybus`.

My script lets the user create a `car` and is later updated by the server with what that car exactly is at random (not possible to predict what it will be). At that time I already have an instance of `car` with owner/milage information but need to extend the created instance with `truck` so that the method `getTopSpeed` is overridden and my `carInstance` becomes `myExtendedInstance instanceof truck===true`

The creation of the base class and subclasses function/extention isn't an issue. Here's that code;

```
function Car(){
}
Car.prototype.getTopSpeed=function(){
    return 100;
}

function Truck(){
    Truck.uber.constructor.call(this);
}
Truck.prototype.getTopSpeed=function(){
    return 20;
}
inherit.call(this, Truck, Car);
```

heres the inherit function by Dustin Diaz/Ross Harmes

```
inherit=function _inherit(subClass, superClass){
    var F=function(){};
    F.prototype=superClass.prototype;
    subClass.prototype=new F();
    subClass.prototype.constructor=subClass;

    subClass.uber=superClass.prototype;
    if (superClass.prototype.constructor===Object.prototype.constructor){
        superClass.prototype.constructor=superClass;
    }
}
```

The question is how to get from an *already created instance* of baseClass to a working subclass and optimally back to the baseClass and to another subclass without the need of creating a new instance of subclass and destroying the instance of baseClass.

Could I just call `myExtendedInstance=inherit(carInstance, Truck)`? Wouldn't that create memory leaks or obscure my prototype chain? And if not, how can I destruct the prototype chain again to return to basic carInstance?

I think I've got a knot somwhere in my head. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: edited and undeleted my answer, i misunderstood the question on the first go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I just call `myExtendedInstance=inherit(carInstance, Truck)`? Wouldn't that create memory leaks or obscure my prototype chain?

No. It wouldn't create memory leaks, but `inherit` just expects *constructor functions* (classes) as arguments not instances.

> And if not, how can I destruct the prototype chain again to return to basic carInstance?

You can't modify the prototype chain of existing objects - unless you use the non-standard [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) (not supported in IE for example).

Instead, you will need to create `myExtendedInstance = new Truck;` and then copy over the owner/milage properties from your old `carInstance`.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer! its what I had expected. I'll therfor need a way to replace an instance with an other. its a bit more complicated than just to copy over attributes (i've got that split out as a "model" anyway) -> the problem is more about updating the references held by other structures. Thats why I wanted to extend an instance with another prototype. Ohwell.. guess I'll brew myself some coffee :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get this to work, but I think this approach (changing the class of an object) is complicated.

I would create a Car class and another class CarSettings or something like that.

Each Car object will contain a CarSettings object which can be modified, or replaced altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The problem i see with inheritance helpers like this is

That the inherited class gets created using `new` and calling the `constructor` without
arguments `subClass.prototype=new F();`
Which can *(in my eyes)*  easily break a little more complex constructors, during the inheritance process, if the constructor relies on specific arguments.

So to get around that and also be able to do what your question is about, <del>i currently use something like this:</del>

Sorry i misunderstood the initial question and modified the helper i used a little bit to support extending und reducting.

```
var base = (function baseConstructor() {
    var obj = {
        create: function instantiation(extend) {
            var instance, args = [].slice.call(arguments);
            if (this === base) {
                throw new SyntaxError("You can't create instances of base");
            } else if (!this.hasOwnProperty("initclosure")) {
                throw new SyntaxError("Cannot create instances without an constructor");
            } else if (this.singleton && this.instances.length !== 0) {
                throw new SyntaxError("You can't create more than one Instance of a Singleton Class");
            } else {
                if (!extend._class || !extend._class.isPrototypeOf(this)) {
                    instance = Object.create(this.pub);
                    this.instances.push(instance);
                } else {
                    args = args.slice(1);
                    extend._class.remove(extend);
                    instance = this.extend(extend);
                }
                this.init.apply(instance, args);
                instance.onCreate();
                return instance;
            }
        },
        extend: function (instance) {
            if (!instance._class.isPrototypeOf(this)) {
                return;
            }
            var extended = Object.create(this.pub);
            for (var propInst in instance) {
                if (instance.hasOwnProperty(propInst)) {
                    extended[propInst] = instance[propInst];
                }
            }
            instance._class.remove(instance);
            this.instances.push(extended);
            return extended;
        },
        reduce: function (instance) {
            if (!instance.instanceOf(this)) {
                return;
            }
            var reduced = Object.create(this.pub);
            for (var propRed in instance) {
                if (instance.hasOwnProperty(propRed)) {
                    reduced[propRed] = instance[propRed];
                }
            }
            instance._class.remove(instance);
            this.instances.push(reduced);
            return reduced;
        },
        remove: function (instance) {
            if (instance.instanceOf(this)) {
                var removed = this.instances.splice(this.instances.indexOf(instance), 1)[0];
                instance.onRemove();
                return removed;
            }
        },
        inherit: function inheritation(specsOpt) {
            specsOpt = specsOpt || {};
            applyDefaults(specsOpt, {
                singleton: false,
                anonymous: false
            });
            var sub = Object.create(this);
            sub.pub = Object.create(this.pub);
            sub.pub.proto = this.pub;
            sub.pub._class = sub;
            sub.instances = [];
            sub.anonymous = specsOpt.anonymous;
            sub.sup = this;
            if (specsOpt.singleton) {
                sub.singleton = specsOpt.singleton;
                sub.getSingleton = getSingleton;
                protect.call(sub, {
                    singleton: {
                        writable: false,
                        configurable: false,
                        enumerable: false
                    },
                    getSingleton: {
                        writable: false,
                        configurable: false
                    }
                });
            }
            return sub;
        },
        initclosure: function Base() {},
        instances: [],
        pub: {
            instanceOf: function (obj) {
                if (!obj || !obj.pub) {
                    return this.className;
                }
                return obj.pub.isPrototypeOf(this);
            },
            onRemove: function () {},
            onCreate: function () {},
            "_class": obj
        }
    };
    /* Helper Functions. --- Use function expressions instead of declarations to get JSHint/Lint strict mode violations
     *
     * TODO: Maybe add an obj.helper Propertie with usefull functions
     */
    var applyDefaults = function (target, obj) {
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                target[prop] = target[prop] || obj[prop];
            }
        }
    };
    var getSingleton = function () { //To get past the strict violation
        return this.instances[0];
    };
    var protect = function (props, desc) { //Maybe change it a little
        for (var prop in props) {
            if (props.hasOwnProperty) {
                Object.defineProperty(this, prop, props[prop] || desc);
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
    /*  End Helpers
     * 
     *  Protecting
     */
    Object.defineProperty(obj, "init", {
        set: function (fn) {
            if (typeof fn !== "function") {
                throw new Error("Expected typeof init to be 'function'");
            } else if (Boolean(fn.name) === this.anonymous) {
                try {
                    throw new Error("Expected the constructor " + (!this.anonymous ? "not " : "") + "to be Anonymous");
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e.stack);
                }
            }
            if (!this.hasOwnProperty("initclosure")) {
                this.initclosure = fn;
                this.pub.constructor = this.init;
                this.pub.className = fn.name;
                protect.call(this.pub, {
                    constructor: false,
                    className: false
                }, {
                    enumerable: false
                });
            }
        },
        get: function () {
            var that = this;
            var init = function init() {
                if (that.pub.isPrototypeOf(this)) {
                    that.initclosure.apply(this, arguments);
                } else {
                    throw new Error("init can't be called directly");
                }
            };
            init.toString = function () {
                return that.initclosure.toString();
            };
            return init;
        }
    });
    obj.toString = function () {
        return "[class " + (this.initclosure.name || "Class") + "]";
    };
    obj.pub.toString = function () {
        return "[instance " + (this.className || "Anonymous") + "]";
    };
    protect.call(obj, {
        create: false,
        inherit: false,
        toString: false,
        onRemove: {
            enumerable: false
        },
        onCreate: {
            enumerable: false
        },
        initclosure: {
            enumerable: false
        }
    }, {
        writable: false,
        configurable: false
    });
    protect.call(obj.pub, {
        instanceOf: false,
        toString: false,
        "_class": {
            enumerable: false
        }
    }, {
        writable: false,
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: false
    });
    return obj;
})();
```

*Note: this relies on `Object.create` which is introduced in ECMAScript 5 and therefore not supported by older browsers*

---

Given the inheritance helper lets create some "Classes"

```
var Car = base.inherit();
Car.pub.getTopSpeed = function () {
    return 100;
};
Car.init = function ClassCar(model) {
    this.model = model || this.model || "";
};
Car.pub.type = "car";
```

Now that we have an inheritable superClass, let `Truck` inherit from `Car`

```
var Truck = Car.inherit();
Truck.pub.getTopSpeed = function () {
    return 20;
};
Truck.pub.type = "truck";
Truck.init = function ClassTruck(model, color) {
    Truck.sup.init.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    this.color = color;
};
```

Then lets create an Instance of `Car`

```
var myCar = Car.create("Porsche");
console.log(myCar.getTopSpeed(), myCar.className); //100, ClassCar
```

Now if I understood you correctly, you want to extend the existing Instance `myCar` of `Car` to become an instance of `Truck`.
*if so, lets do this*

```
var myExtendedTruck = Truck.extend(myCar);
console.log(myExtendedTruck.getTopSpeed(), myExtendedTruck.className); //20, ClassTruck
console.log(myExtendedTruck.instanceOf(Truck)); //true
```

This simply sets up the extended prototype chain copys the instance variables to the new Truck instance. So the `Car` instance is now a `Truck` instance

Or if you want to use the constructor as well.
`create` works as well when passing an Instance of a superclass.
Then it gets extended and initialized.

```
var myConstructedExtendedTruck = Truck.create(myCar, myCar.model, "Yellow");
console.log(myConstructedExtendedTruck.getTopSpeed(), myConstructedExtendedTruck.model, myConstructedExtendedTruck.color); //20 , Porsche , Yellow
```

Now we have a extend `Car` instance, which is now instance of `Truck` and got properly constructed by the `Trucks` constructor.

Now if i got this right you want to be able to get back to a superclass Instance too.

```
var myReducedCar = Car.reduce(myExtendedTruck);
console.log(myReducedCar.getTopSpeed(), myReducedCar.className); //100, ClassCar
console.log(myReducedCar.instanceOf(Truck)); //false
```

Heres an [Example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/opigom/1/edit) to fiddle around a bit

*Edit note: Fixed the code to properly move instances in the Classes `instances` array*

Comment: thanks for your extended answer! Is there a pattern name for this or do you have more ressources providing a more indepth analysis?

Comment: You're welcome =) 
Umm i don't really know if theres a pattern name for something like this, i just wrote this a bit ago with no specific pattern in mind, so im afraid the only thing i can offer you is to answer any further questions regarding the code.
Cheers